# window.onerror doesnt work with Angular 5

Tags: javascript, html, angular

In my Angular app I want to send me error details to my spring endpoint when cricital angular error/bundle error occurs - Angular errors are catched by handleErrors.
So I heard about window.onerror function, so I added this in my index.html file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Frontend</title>
  <base href="/">
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onerror = function (msg, url, lineNo, columnNo, error) {
    var string = msg.toLowerCase();
    var substring = "script error";
      var message = [
        'Message: ' + msg,
        'URL: ' + url,
        'Line: ' + lineNo,
        'Column: ' + columnNo,
        'Error object: ' + JSON.stringify(error)
      ].join(' - ');
    alert(message);
  };
</script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

Later I want send error data to server, but now I'm just testing it. 
And when I specially create error which occurs an Angular compile error I have no alert, just failed to compile 
[image]
or blank page with get

[image]

and looks like onerror doesnt catch it.

Comment: It's not a JavaScript error. `Failed to compile` is a message displayed by the **hot loader** used by WebPack to reload the application after a build.

Comment: So is there any way to catch this error? I thought that this will create a js error also

Comment: You can try to intercept calls to `console.error` instead, which will let you catch the red text messages printed to JS console, but you don't get any useful debugging information beyond whatever message your framework decided to print.

Comment: Hi @Adam what is the exact directory name of your project?

Comment: This is not a **browser** error. WebPack failed to build the project. Your application will **never** run so there is no way to give you an example of JavaScript code that will catch this. The code itself will never be executed.

Answer (score 1):

Angular provides a common method to handle Error. What you should do is to create a class implements ErrorHandler:

```js
import { ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';

export class AppGlobalErrorhandler implements ErrorHandler {
  handleError(error) {
   console.warn("customize catch execption:"+error);
  }
}
```

Then, in `app.module.ts`, you tell Angular to use our Custom Error Handler, configing in providers:

```js
providers: [
  // ...
  {
    provide: ErrorHandler,
    useClass: AppGlobalErrorhandler
  }
]
```

Reference：https://golb.hplar.ch/2018/10/global-errorhandler-angular.html